# What's the difference between Spring Cloud loadbalancer and Ribbon?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

Our team is planning to move from

1. Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon to Spring Cloud LoadBalancer and using spring-cloud-kubernetes as discovery client.
2. Using Spring Cloud Gateway instead of Zuul
3. and Resilience4j instead of Hystrix.

What are the required changes needed and do we need to change the equivalent property. Can you please help where we need to start?

Comment: We've made a presentation on that 1 year ago; it's still mostly up-to-date: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mINNQ3zpRrE&t=1225s

Comment: Thank you, but do you something documented in ppt or some file?

Comment: We have SC LoadBalancer documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-loadbalancer and sample project with the code from that presentation: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-intro-demo. The slides can be found here: https://speakerdeck.com/olgamaciaszek/how-to-live-in-a-post-spring-cloud-netflix-world

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek interesting presentation

Answer (score 2):

You need to go through the documents of spring.io -
[spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-loadbalancer)

Also, create first one sample project and run , see how Cloud LoadBalancer made the concept of load balancing more simpler and easier.